# Will Dictionary<TKey, TValue> use TKey.Equals and TKey.GetHashCode?

Tags: c#

I have implemented a Dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<ErrorHashKey, ErrorRow> dictionary;
```

I have defined `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in the `ErrorHashKey` class. I am currently writing up some documentation for the project, and came accross this from the [IEqualityComparer Interface doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Dictionary requires an equality implementation to
>   determine whether keys are equal. You can specify an implementation of
>   the IEqualityComparer generic interface by using a constructor that
>   accepts a comparer parameter; if you do not specify an implementation,
>   the default generic equality comparer EqualityComparer.Default is
>   used. If type TKey implements the System.IEquatable generic
>   interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

I am not doing anything that the documentation specifies (or at least I don't think I am). I do not pass a comparer in the constructor parameter nor do I create an `EqualityComparer.Default` comparer.

Is the `System.IEquatable<T> generic interface` automatically implemented in every class created? Should I be defining an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default comparer will call `object.Equals` or `object.GetHashCode` (your overridden methods) if `IEquatable<T>` is not implemented.  This is documented at the [documentation for `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  You don't need to do anything extra, and no, `IEquatable<T>` is not automatically implemented in your class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer id in your question:

> if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic equality
>   comparer EqualityComparer.Default is used

EqualityComparer.Default is using the `Equals` method if you're not implementing IEquatable.

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the
>   System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an
>   EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of
>   Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx